# How can I test all my inputs on a form at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I test my inputs and leave the whole form or two entries blank, I only get the first input not filled in with the class add of notValid. I would think this would test everything at the same time but only input will get the new class. Any help would be appreciated.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (title.value.length == 0) {
            title.classList.add('notValid');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (author.value.length == 0) {
            author.classList.add('notValid');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (pages.value.length == 0) {
            pages.classList.add('notValid');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Library</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="text" id='addBookBtn' class='addBookBtn'>Add Books</button>
    <div class="book-container" id='book-container'>
        <h1>add a book</h1>
        <label for="read">Read?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class='readInput' id='readInput'>
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" class='title' id='title' placeholder='Add a Title'>
        <label for="author">Author:</label>
        <input type="text" class='author' id='author' placeholder='Add an Author'>
        <label for="pages">Pages:</label>
        <input type="number" class='pages' id='pages' placeholder=' Number of Pages'>
        <button class='btn' id='btn' type="submit">Add</button>
    </div>

    <div class='newBookContainer' id='newBookContainer'></div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Can we see the HTML that goes along with this please?

Comment: yes, post updated

Comment: You never passed in the `EventObject`, `e` into you Listener function, so `e` is `undefined`... but there is no need to `e.preventDefault()`. You're supposed to use that on a `form` Element to prevent submission. That's not a form Element.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the event param in you eventListener

```
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {}
```

Another thing you could do to avoid checking for individual values of inputs manually, you can loop through all input fields by adding them similar classnames or just query all the input fields inside form.
Also, Having such number of inputs, it's a good way to add them inside `form`

```
                              // optional: add the input class for all inputs
<input type="checkbox" class="input readInput" id="readInput" />
```

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input'); // or query the classnames you've given for all input fields


form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
   
   // or simply use Array.from(inputs).forEach()
   // calling Array.prototype.slice.call will convert NodeLists into Array
   Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs).forEach((el) => {
     if (el.value.length === 0) {
       el.classList.add('notValid');
     } else {
       el.classList.remove('notValid');
     }
   })
});
```

```css
.notValid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button type="text" id='addBookBtn' class='addBookBtn'>Add Books</button>
  <div class="book-container" id='book-container'>
    <form id="form">
        <h1>add a book</h1>
        <label for="read">Read?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class='input readInput' id='readInput'>
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" class='input title' id='title' placeholder='Add a Title'>
        <label for="author">Author:</label>
        <input type="text" class='input author' id='author' placeholder='Add an Author'>
        <label for="pages">Pages:</label>
        <input type="number" class='input pages' id='pages' placeholder=' Number of Pages'>
        <button class='btn' id='btn' type="submit">Add</button>
    
  </form>
   </div>
```